# Serialize data on mysql data types

Tags: php, mysql

What is the best data types for serialize data?

Answer (score 4):

if you know how long the serialized data will be you can use `varchar`, otherwise id use `text`. it might just be best to use `text` anyways.

Comment: VARCHAR only if the size of the data does not exceed about 65k bytes, the maximum row size (though this is for all fields in the table, not just for a single field).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how big the data you want to serialize is. It could be `text` or `longtext`.

Btw, very often (but not always) storing of serialized data is a bad design, which should be reimplemented using `N:M` or `1:N` (many-to-many or one-to-many) relations

Answer (score 1):

If the data is just a generic pile of bytes, such as an image, then use a BLOB.

If it's a pile of text, use one of the TEXT types.

Otherwise, it depends upon what kind of data you're dealing with.